# git status -s showing D for few files in the second column

Tags: windows-xp, git, github, status

I have a local git repository running on my windows machine. The remote origin is in github.
After executing a `git pull` when I run `git status -s` command, it is displaying some files with `D` mark. But I have not deleted any files in my local directory. Why this is showing `'D'` Mark for files which I have not deleted? Is it safe to commit changes and push to the remote repository in this situation?

Comment: Maybe "you" didn't delete those files, but something else did?  Are you using Git Bash or similar?  What does `ls -l` show for the files that `git` says were deleted?  And no, committing changes is probably not safe.

Comment: I am using Git Bash, those files are not in local file system.

Comment: If you haven't made changes to your working copy, try running `git reset --hard`.